# PopTrayU - 'Error connecting with SSL'?

Tags: windows, ssl, tls, pop3, delphi

Without having made any changes, starting in July 2020, I got:

```
An error occurred.
Error Type: EIdOSSLConnectError
Error connecting with SSL.
EOF was observed that violates the protocol
```

[image: In PoptrayU: 'Error connecting with SSL']

I have several email service providers, but this happens only for one of them.

---

**Background**
I have been using Poptray and PoptrayU for almost two decades – on a daily
basis.
It helps me keep track of a dozen email accounts – easily.
I cannot imagine a life without PoptrayU.
It has become truly indispensable for me.

#### References

- [Direct link to the installer of version 5.2.6](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poptrayu/files/PopTrayU%205.2.6%20Installer.exe/download)
- [Direct link to the OpenSSL for PopTrayU installer, version 1.0.2c](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poptrayupop3ssl/files/OpenSSL%20for%20PopTray%204.1%2B/OpenSSL_1.0.2c_for_PopTrayU_Setup.exe/download)
- [The home page of PoptrayU](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poptrayu/files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggested solution

> *Error Type: EIdOSSLConnectError*

I found a workaround that works for me. 
For a failing email address, click *Accounts > Advanced Connection Settings*. 
Change *SSL/TLS Version* from *Auto* to *TLS 1.2*.

[image: Fails – SSL/TLS Version is set to 'Auto']

[image: Succeeds – SSL/TLS Version is set to 'TLS 1.2']

Note that TLS is the successor of the deprecated SSL, but [*TLS is still commonly referred to as SSL*](https://flickerleap.com/internet-security-ssl-tls-https).

#### The author's solution

The author of PoptrayU suggested the above solution herself – as early as in June 2016. 
*In the advanced connection settings, you may need to select the SSL/TLS version manually to select one compatible with your server instead of selecting Auto.
I suggest starting with one of the higher number TLS versions …* 
Source: [Solution suggested by the author of PoptrayU](https://sourceforge.net/p/poptrayu/discussion/general/thread/27451340#c2b7).

#### Some more error messages you may encounter

- *Account configured for SSL, but SSL is not available* is likely caused by a failure to 
  install the *OpenSSL_1.0.2c_for_PopTrayU* plugin. You can get it from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poptrayupop3ssl/files/OpenSSL%20for%20PopTray%204.1%2B/OpenSSL_1.0.2c_for_PopTrayU_Setup.exe/download). 
  (Please wait 5 seconds after clicking the link!)
- *Socket Error 11001: Host not found* is typical when *you entered a mail server that doesn't exist*. 
  For example, when I enter `popwrong.mail.yahoo.com` instead of `pop.mail.yahoo.com`, 
  then I get *Socket Error 11001: Host not found*.
- *Error Type: EIdException* typically means that the password is wrong.

#### Limitations

PoptrayU does **not** work with Gmail or Yahoo Mail. 
– Neither of those two email providers supplies a simple POP3 service with a password. 
I hardly ever use Gmail.
And I use my Yahoo Mail account only for junk emails.

#### PoptrayU is free and open-source

Keep in mind that PoptrayU is **not** commercial software and that you cannot buy support for it. 
I don't know the author in person, but I *do* know that she created this software 
*in her spare time for free*, for which I am immensely grateful.

### References

- [Internet security: what is SSL, TLS and HTTPS?](https://flickerleap.com/internet-security-ssl-tls-https)
- [Solution suggested by the author of PoptrayU](https://sourceforge.net/p/poptrayu/discussion/general/thread/27451340#c2b7)
- [Direct link to download the TLS 1.0.2c plugin – wait 5 seconds!](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poptrayupop3ssl/files/OpenSSL%20for%20PopTray%204.1%2B/OpenSSL_1.0.2c_for_PopTrayU_Setup.exe/download)
- [The issue discussed at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/poptrayu/discussion/general/thread/487156723e#a5fc)

Comment: Consider using Pop Peeper (Esumsoft) as a newer and good alternative to Pop Tray which I used up to Windows 8.  Pop Peeper is a good match to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The above workaround is not working. If you **check** Use SSL/TLS in your Connection Settings and test your account you get *Error Type: EIdException: Account configured for SSL, but SSL is not available*. If you **uncheck** Use SSL/TLS in the Connection Settings and test your account you get *Socket Error 11001: Host not found.* Who wants to spend his or her precious time troubleshooting bugs in PopTrayU when good bug-free alternatives are available? If the makers of PopTrayU do not come up with a working version they will be abandoned by their loyal users.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, note that I have updated
[my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1599946)
to solve the issues raised here.